# Install locust in Anaconda

Tags: python, locust

I´m was trying to install locustio following this steps (http://docs.locust.io/en/latest/installation.html), in my terminal:

```
pip install locustio
```

I get this:

```
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I also have tried with easy_install:

```
sudo easy_install locustio
```

I get the same error. After that, yesterday I was looking for information about this, and some people says that you may to need install gcc.

```
brew install gcc
```

I get this message:

```
Warning: gcc-5.3.0 already installed
```

After a couple of hours looking for information, I read about Anaconda, I install Anaconda and I create my new environment... and in my new environment I get this again:

```
  ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I´m getting crazy. I would like to work in environments but I need some of help to do this because I lost a lot time trying to resolve this problem to use locustio.

I´m using Mac Yosemite 10.10.3

My Anaconda version is 3.19.0

My Python version is 2.7.11

My gcc is gcc-5.3.0

Someone can help me?

I just wanna launch locustio in my pc =(

Comment: Not sure this will help, but I came across a similar issue in the past and as far as I remember I solved it by installing `pkg-config`.

Comment: I have lost 6 hours and finally I have installed a Linux machine in Paralles... but yes, this is the solution, it works to me. Thanks =)